# Match closest set of points to another set of (predefined) points

Tags: math, geometry, computer-vision, gis

I have 10 sets of points which I call templates that I have manually classified from 0 to 10. Each point is a X, Y coordinate in a text file. Each template has 5-8 points. I have new sets of points that I want to classify as one of the templates. The points are scale and rotation invariant. Each set of points may not have the same number of points with the template that it corresponds to. there's also differences in the X,Y coordinates (meaning they're not identical) but they are similar.
So I think what I need is the closest set of points (from the templates) to another set of points (the one I have as input).

I can generate polygons from each set of points so the question can become: how can I match the closest polygon to a set of points.

Maybe generate some signature and grade the set of points against each of the templates?

Comment: to the centroid of the set of points?

Comment: What do you mean by "The points are scale and rotation invariant"? That you can rotate/translate your new set of points to fit a template or not?